# Divergence of an improper integral - |cos(x^2)|/x^q

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove divergence of the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\left|\cos{x^2}\right|}{x^q}dx$, where $0<q<1$, by applying the mean-value theorem to $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\left|\cos{x^2}\right|}{x^q}dx$: there exists $c_n\in [n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$ such that $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\left|\cos{x^2}\right|}{x^q}dx=\left|\cos{c_n^2}\right|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{1}{x^q}dx$. So if I can show that $\inf{\left|\cos{c_n^2}\right|}\neq 0$, we would have the divergence, by comparison with $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^q}dx$. It isn't apparent to me how to prove that bit.

I know that the divergence can also be proved by noting that $\left|\cos{x^2}\right|\geq\cos^2{x^2}=\frac{1+\cos{2x^2}}{2}$ and using a test akin to Dirichlet's test for series to prove the convergence of $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos{2x^2}}{x^q}dx$.

But I'd like to know if my idea can be finished.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the issues with the mean value theorem by proceeding like this: Change variables from $x$ to $x^2$ as one of the answerers suggested, so that one is attempting to show divergence of ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} {|\cos(x)| \over x^r}\,dx}$, where now ${1 \over 2} < r < 1$. Next, note that one has 
$$\int_{2\pi}^{\infty} {|\cos(x)| \over x^r}\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}{|\cos(x)| \over x^r}\,dx$$
Since the denominator is monotone increasing, this is bounded below by
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}{|\cos(x)| \over (2\pi(n+1))^r}\,dx$$
$$= {1 \over (2\pi)^r}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over (n+1)^r}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}|\cos(x)|\,dx$$
Since $\cos(x)$ has period $2\pi$, the integral above has some fixed value $C > 0$, so the above is equal to
$$C {1 \over (2\pi)^r}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over (n+1)^r}$$
Since $r < 1$ this diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Careful.  Showing $\cos{c_n^2}\neq 0 $ does *not* show divergence.  (Consider $\cos{c_n^2}=n^{-(n!)}$)

For your idea to work you need to show that there exists $c_n$ such that $c_n\leq \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}|\cos x^2|dx$ and $c_n$ does not go to zero too *quickly*.  That is we need to bound the integral from below.  (Using inequalities rather than the equality given by the mean value theorem will suffice.)

Then 
$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{|\cos x^2|}{x^q}dx\geq c_n\cdot \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{1}{((n+1)\pi)^q}dx=\frac{c_n\pi}{((n+1)\pi)^q}$$ 
Where the inequality follows since $\frac{1}{((n+1)\pi)^q}\leq x^q $ on this interval, and the average of $\cos x^2$ is greater than $c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zarrax has pointed out, we could look at ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} {|\cos(x)| \over x^r}\,dx}$ where ${1 \over 2} < r < 1$.

We could argue that if ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} {\cos^2(x) \over x^r}\,dx}$ diverges then by the comparison test our integral diverges, since ${|\cos(x)| \over x^r} \geq {\cos^2(x) \over x^r}$.

Showing divergence of ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} {\cos^2(x) \over x^r}\,dx}$ is simple if we note the fact that: $$\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^r}=\frac{1}{2x^r}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2x^r}$$

But ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{2x^r}\,dx}$ converges by Dirichlets test and ${\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{2x^r}\,dx}$ obviously diverges hence $$\int_1^{\infty} {\cos^2(x) \over x^r}\,dx$$ diverges as needed.